# How to add login page to Shell as ShellItem without being shown as a FlyoutItem

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

When I add loading and login pages to the Shell like this:

```xml
    <!-- Loading/Start Page -->
    <ShellItem Route="loading">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:WelcomePage}" />
    </ShellItem>

    <!-- Login and Registration Page -->
    <ShellContent Route="login"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:LoginPage}">
    </ShellContent>
```

It works, but pages are also added to Shell flyout items as item without name, but when I press it I go back to Loading or Login page ...

I cannot figure out how to fix this ...

Do somebody faced with the same issue ?

Comment: I believe you mean flyout item

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `Shell` item that is in your AppShell not to be created as a flyout item, then you need to set the attached property [Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#set-flyoutitem-visibility) to `false`, it default value is `true`.

```
 <!-- Loading/Start Page -->
    <ShellItem Route="loading" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:WelcomePage}" />
    </ShellItem>

    <!-- Login and Registration Page -->
    <ShellContent Route="login" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:LoginPage}">
    </ShellContent>
```

#### Note

This property is available starting from Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012

#### Related question

[How can you restrict/control the navigation routes the user can visit based on login status/role?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65186262)

Comment: I have been googling for so long and this finally solved it for me. thank you. here, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

In such a case we always set the **LoginPage** as the MainPage of the whole app firstly .

```
MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

And set it as Shell when finish login .

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new YourShell();
```

Comment: No, it is not possible, because I did that previously, but I had some artifacts during switch from Page to Shell ... Artifacts was a yellow background color during switching from Page to Shell

Comment: Update the version of XF to latest version .

Comment: What did you mean ? It was an issue with previous version ? I have been always on latest version of Xamarin Forms ...

Comment: Or you could push a modal page in onApeearing method .