# How can I make Xamarin show the hamburger icon rather than the back button?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin `Shell` application has a flyout defined as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="..."
       xmlns:viewModels="..."
       x:Class="...">

       <FlyoutItem x:Name="A1" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
          <ShellContent x:Name="a1">
             <local:Homepage/>
          </ShellContent>
       </FlyoutItem>

       <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
          <ShellContent Route="Settings" ContentTemplate="..." />
       </FlyoutItem>

       <FlyoutItem x:Name="LoginFlyoutItem" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
          <ShellContent x:Name="Login" Route="Login" ContentTemplate="..." />
       </FlyoutItem>
    
</Shell>
```

I want the `Login` page to perform a navigation to the `a1` page after the user logs in with an

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Homepage));
```

The issue is that the `a1` page shows the back button on the top left corner when opened, but I want it to show the normal hamburger icon to open the flyout. I would expect the back button when using the `PushAsync()` method, but not using the `GoToAsync()` one. I don’t want the `a1` page to be considered a “child” of the login page, but I simply want the view model to navigate to the `a1` page. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Assuming you don't want the user to navigate again to login page. Have you tried to set IsVisible property to false on your Login page upon user logging? If your app structure allows it this https://stackoverflow.com/q/65186262 could be helpful.

Comment: I don't want to hide the login page, i just want a1 not to be treated like a child of the login page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `//` to switch to a different navigation stack instead of becoming a child page:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(Homepage)}");
```

Comment: I was setting a global route with `Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Homepage), typeof(Homepage))`, and that caused a conflict. I removed the global route and now it works.