# Xamarin Creating new Instancaes of AppShell

Tags: xamarin

in my Application when logging out, I remove all Credentials and call
`Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();`
and I'm wondering if this is causing memory leaks or if I'm meant to do that.

From my understanding that is the way to go when I don't want the user to be able to navigate back.

---

EDIT:

In my application the user should only see all pages when he is logged.  All pages (except login page) use following class:

```
public class LoggedContentPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly WebService _webService = new WebService();
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            if (! await _webService.IsAuthenticated())
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
            }
        }
    }
```

In turn my Login page uses:

```
bool success = await _webService.Authenticate(userCred);
if (success)
{
    Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

Pressing the "back" button should not take the user back to the previous page in this case. What is the recommended way of navigating like this?

Comment: I don't think it's a good approach, I believe you can manage that otherwise, could you precise your requirement in more details "I don't want the user to be able to navigate back" ?

Comment: Does [How can you restrict/control the navigation routes the user can visit based on login status/role?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65186262) answers your requirements ?

Comment: yes, particularly this line `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Page2");` does. I will assume this is the proper way to go. Thanks