# xamarin Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

error:

```
xamarin Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff'
```

error is on line  `auth = DependencyService.Get<IAuth>();`

shared project

```
 public partial class PhoneAuthPage : ContentPage
{
      IAuth auth;

        public PhoneAuthPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            auth = DependencyService.Get<IAuth>();
       }
       ...
}
```

android project

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AuthDriod))]
namespace TestApp_Firebase.Droid.Views.PhoneViews
{
    public class AuthDriod : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks, IAuth
    {
...
}
```

AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell ...
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp_Firebase.Views"
   xmlns:PhoneViews="clr-namespace:TestApp_Firebase.vPhone"
   ...>

<FlyoutItem Title="Main Home Page" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <ShellContent Route="MainHomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainHomePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Phone Auth Page" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <ShellContent Route="PhoneAuthPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate PhoneViews:PhoneAuthPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

Comment: it seems duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/67826624/5228202

Answer (score 0):

In my case, nuget pack `"Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement"` broken appshell menu. Not know why.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working by downgrading my

> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base

To version 116.0.1.  Did not touch anything else