# How to remove the navigation bar of a ContentPage when using Shell

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, navigationbar, xamarin.forms.shell

I have a registration/login page set up and I use shell to navigate between them but i want to remove the header (I am not sure if that's it's name)

[image: That blue header at the top witch is used for flyout menu]

I have tried adding

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
```

this in my login page but with no effect. Maybe because my xaml pages are not defined as navigation pages.

Here is my Login.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Appointments.ViewModels"  
             x:DataType="viewmodel:RegLogViewModel"
             x:Class="Appointments.Views.RegisterPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:RegLogViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Grid
            RowDefinitions="130,300,*,70">


        <Label
            Grid.Row="0"
            Text="REGISTRATION"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            FontSize="40"
            />

        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="1">

            <Entry Placeholder="username" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="email" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="password" Text="{Binding Password}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="confirm password" Text="{Binding PasswordConfirmation}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="phone number" Text="{Binding Phone}"/>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label 
                    Text="This account is for a hairstylist"
                    FontSize="20"/>
                <Switch/>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Text="Register"
            FontSize="Large"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            CornerRadius="10"
            Padding="20,0"
            BackgroundColor="Aquamarine"
            Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
            
            />

        <Label
            Grid.Row="3"
            Text="Already a user? Login"
            FontSize="20"
            TextDecorations="Underline"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
>

            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GoToLoginCommand}"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>

        </Label>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

I guess you only need the `ContentPage` definition

And i have register a route to this page in my `AppShell.xaml.cs` and in my `AppShell.xaml` i've set `ShellContent` to the actual page and that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `Shell`, instead of setting the attached proeprty `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar` you need to set `Shell.NavBarIsVisible`:

```
<ContentPage ...
       Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
```

#### Related question

[How can you restrict/control the navigation routes the user can visit based on login status/role?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65186262/5228202)