# Xamarin forms shell getting confused with Login screen not navigating to home content

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So the below is my xamrain forms shell I am having an issue when I am using my tab bar.
I have a login page so in my App.xaml.cs I have the folowing

```
    public App()
    {        
         Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider
         .RegisterLicense("");//remove license for security
        DevExpress.XamarinForms.Editors.Initializer.Init();
        DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.Initializer.Init();

        InitializeComponent();

       MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    }
```

As you see I am putting putting my main page to the login page however when I click my home button below when I am in my add pages the home page does not navigate back to the main screen.

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:THEHOCKEYLAB.Views"
   Title="THEHOCKEYLAB"
   x:Class="THEHOCKEYLAB.AppShell">

<!--
    The overall app visual hierarchy is defined here, along with navigation.

    https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/
-->

<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>

<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="Menu" Icon="home.png"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AdminMenuPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Settings" Icon="settings.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}" />
</TabBar>

<!--
    If you would like to navigate to this content you can do so by calling
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
-->
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

So for example here I have an issue

```
private async void btnAddStudent_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("StudentsPage");
}
```

When I try to come back from this page clicking the  home nothing nappens can someone please explain to me as to why that is?

Comment: If using Shell, supposed to be `MainPage = new AppShell();` in App.xaml.cs. And also check AppShell.xaml.cs to see if the route of StudentsPage was registered there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65186262/5228202

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to achieve this .

---

##### Include LoginPage into AppShell

1. Set `AppShell` as `MainPage` in `App`.
2. Place Two `Tabbar` in AppShell , and place `LoginPage` first than `HomePage`, and set  different `Route` for the two `Tabbar`.

   ```
   <TabBar Route="Login">
     <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
   </TabBar>

   <TabBar Route="Home">
       <ShellContent Title="Menu" Icon="home.png"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AdminMenuPage}" />
       <ShellContent Title="Settings" Icon="settings.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}" />
   </TabBar>
   ```
3. Call `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Home");` when login in , Call `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Login");` when login out .

##### Don't Include LoginPage into AppShell

1. Set `LoginPage` as `MainPage` in `App` at first.
2. Call `MainPage = new AppShell();` When login in , Call `MainPage = new LoginPage();` when login out .

Comment: This was indeed the solution thanks

Comment: Odd I am still having an issue its refusing to go back to the main menu page

Comment: I did a small capture video to show u what happnes the home button is not going to the menu page when it should do when in some lists. https://www.screencast.com/t/AAyOLqVtsOut

Comment: Are you using the way 1 or way 2? And do you want to go back to login page when clicking `check in` item in home page ?