# how to use App Shell with different Flyout items per page

Tags: xamarin.forms, flyout, app-shell

I'm new to Xamarin forms and I have this requirement of creating the login page which logs two user types (Customer , Admin).
and after that it logs users to their profile .
the problem is each profile have a different flyout items .
so I have no idea how to achieve this and what is the best practice .
to demonstrate the idea here is a picture.[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187674/5228202 create other properties like IsAdmin and handle visibility by binding to IsVisible on the same appshell

Answer (score 0):

In your Login Button, you can do like this in XAML:

`<Button ... Clicked="Login_Clicked" ... />`

for this username you can check in your db if is admin or customer and return a value to know it. Create two pages (AdminPage and CustomerPage), and in your code-behind:

```
private async void Login_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (Database.CheckUser() == "admin"){
     Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new AdminPage());
   } else {
       Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new CustomerPage());
   }
}
```

IF you don't want to create two pages, you can create one page (UserPage), passing the verification of what user is, and then in your code-behind you can set the buttons/labels and their functions, e.g:

```
UserPage.xaml.cs

public UserPage(string checkUser){

 if(checkUser == "admin"){
  ProcessAdmin();
 }
 else{
  ProcessCustomer();
 }
}

ProcessAdmin(){
 btn1.Text = "Admin Profiler";
 btn2.Text = "Home Page";
 ...
 ...
 btn1.Clicked => (s,e) {
   //do something for admin profiler button
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of page in FlyoutPage:**Flyout** and **Detail**,so you can change them depends on the role of users.
Here is a example:

****FlyoutPage**:**set the flyout depends on the flag set in the constructor

```
public partial class FlyoutMainPage : FlyoutPage
    {
        public FlyoutMainPage(bool flag)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (flag)
            { Flyout = new MenuPage1();
                Detail = new NavigationPage(new TestPage1());
            }
            else
           Flyout = new MenuPage2();
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new TestPage1());
        }
    }
}
```

**Navigate**:set flag value based on action

```
    async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      await Navigation.PushAsync(new FlyoutMainPage(true));
    }

   async void Button_Clicked_1(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new FlyoutMainPage(false));
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is using the flyout from Shell

Comment: Then just change the navigation part it still will work