# xamarin navigation login management

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

At the entrance of the tabbed project I made, I want the login page to come first, then I want the project to open.
I tried many ways;

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
```

Problem; tabbar doesn't show

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("Page1", typeof(Page1));
```

Problem; Nothing happens

Codes;

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(page1), typeof(page1));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(page2), typeof(page2));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(page3), typeof(page3));
    }

}
```

AppShell.xaml

```
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Route="page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:page1}" />
    <ShellContent Route="page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:page2}" />
    <ShellContent Route="page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:page1}" />
</TabBar>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        //MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
}
```

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

I tried so many ways hope you can help me solve it.

Comment: The question is not clear, could you reformulate? I thin a better approach is to stay inside Shell (keep the same MainPage) whenever it is possible, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/65186262/

Comment: this has been discussed many times - https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+appshell+login

Comment: one simple approach is to set `MainPage = new LoginPage();` on app startup - then after the login has completed, set `MainPage = new AppShell();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this .

---

##### Include LoginPage into AppShell

1. Set `AppShell` as `MainPage` in `App`.
2. Place Two `Tabbar` in AppShell , and place `LoginPage` first than `HomePage`, and set  different `Route` for the two `Tabbar`.

   ```
   <TabBar Route="Login">
     <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
   </TabBar>

   <TabBar Route="Home">
       <ShellContent Title="Menu" Icon="home.png"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AdminMenuPage}" />
       <ShellContent Title="Settings" Icon="settings.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}" />
   </TabBar>
   ```
3. Call `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Home");` when login in , Call `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Login");` when login out .

##### Don't Include LoginPage into AppShell

1. Set `LoginPage` as `MainPage` in `App` at first.
2. Call `MainPage = new AppShell();` When login in , Call `MainPage = new LoginPage();` when login out .