# In MAUI how can I Show different appshell tabbars depending on the user role?

Tags: c#, ios, mobile, maui

I would like to have a set of 2 or more TabBars, and depending on the loggedin user role I would like to show the first set of tabbars or the second
I'm not sure if this is the right approach or if there is something better

so for example if the logged in user is User.UserTypeId = 2 then show

```
`<tabbar><ShellContent
Title="Home"
ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:HomePage}"
Route="HomePage" />`
```

and if the logged in user is User.UserTypeId = 3 then show

```
`<tabbar><ShellContent
Title="Home3"
ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:HomePage3}"
Route="HomePage3" />`
```

I cannot find any examples on this, can you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you restrict/control the navigation routes the user can visit based on login status/role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186262/how-can-you-restrict-control-the-navigation-routes-the-user-can-visit-based-on-l)